# QSqlDatabase::open() always returns true Qt 5.3.2

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qsqldatabase

Independently of the parameter that I set to the `setDatabaseName` function, the `open` function always returns true. Is that normal?

For example:

If I ran the following code:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

db.setDatabaseName("");

if( db.open() )
{
    qDebug() << "open";
}
```

The open function returns true.

What I expect is that the open function only returns true if it was successfully connected to the database.

I already find some topics but none solved my problem:

[Qt 5.5 QSqlDatabase::open() always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276862/qt-5-5-qsqldatabaseopen-always-returns-true)

[QSqlDatabase::open() always returns true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139103/qsqldatabaseopen-always-returns-true)

[QSqlDatabase open always returns true after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014413/qsqldatabase-open-always-returns-true-after-update)

I am using SQLite and Qt 5.3.2.

Comment: For sqlite it creates a database if the file does not exist. Although I am not sure what it is supposed to do if you give it a blank file name.

Comment: @drescherjm, thanks. I didn't know that. So, if I need to check if the database file exists, do I need to do it "manually"?

Comment: In my code I check if the file exists.

Comment: Thanks, @drescherjm. I did it using: `QFile::exists( dbPath )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal, because the connection succeeds for you.

Specifically, if a database doesn't exist, sqlite will create it. The connection will fail only if the database cannot be created with a given filepath.

If you want to check if a file exists, use `QFile::exists()`.